# Back to launcher screen after printing

Tags: java, android, android-intent, cycle

I am programming an application inside Android studio. Now I want my application to never close and work as a cycle. I know I can do that with the Intent class and configure the Manifest.xml file for all the activities that are inside my application.

But to print I go outside of my application to get to a printpreview with the printsettings. At this moment - when the printing is finished - that preview will close and go back (automatically) to my last activity (the one that comes before the printpreview). Now instead of going to that previous activity, I want to go back to the startpage (category.LAUNCHER).

But that doesn't work with programming with the Intent class because there is no xml file of the printpreview. Because it is a method which creates a bitmapfile and goes outside of my application to print.

```
 /**
 * Method which creates a bitmap of the picture with the Odisee logo and 
 * goes to the printpreviewpage with settings.
 *
 */
private void doPhotoPrint() {
    try {
        //Creates object from PrintHelper class
        PrintHelper photoPrinter = new PrintHelper(this);

        //Scales image
        photoPrinter.setScaleMode(PrintHelper.SCALE_MODE_FILL);

        // Find the last picture
        String[] projection = new String[]{
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID,
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA,
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN,
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.MIME_TYPE};
        final Cursor cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver()
                .query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, null,
                        null, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC");

        String imageLocation = null;

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            imageLocation = cursor.getString(1);

        }
        File imageFile = new File(imageLocation);

        //Creates bitmapfile to print
        if (imageFile.exists()) {
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;

            //Gets the resources (last taken picture + Odisee logo)
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageLocation);
            Bitmap bitmap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.logo_odisee2);
            Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), bitmap.getConfig());

            //Draws the Odisee logo onto the picture
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, new Matrix(),null);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap2,950,550,null);

            //Sets printer orientation to landscape
            photoPrinter.setOrientation(PrintHelper.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

            //Goes to screen to print the bitmap
            photoPrinter.printBitmap("photobooth", bmOverlay);
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Fout!");
    }
}
```

If I create an Intent object it will either skip the printpreview part or crash after being printed. So I am wondering if there is another possible way to fix this issue and keep the application running?

```
    <activity android:name=".startPagina">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: as I read documentation you can send callback to [https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/print/PrintHelper.html#printBitmap(java.lang.String, android.graphics.Bitmap, android.support.v4.print.PrintHelper.OnPrintFinishCallback)](printBitmap) with `PrintHelper.OnPrintFinishCallback` interface

so after print finished you can start app's Launcher activity

Comment: @armanso I will give it a try! Thanks for your help!